# R How to extract everything in all paragraphs after a specific word?

Tags: r, regex, string

Hello I'm looking for a R code to delete every words in all paragraphs after a specific term like.
Example looking for "Talk:" and replace everything until a new pargraph.
I tried regex and spend time but can't succeed ("fjeaofiz" always present).

```r
x <- c("12 3456 789", "Talk: zpfozefpozjgzigzehgoi oezjgzogzjgoezjgo \r fjeaofiz ", "", NA, "Talk: 667")
stri_sub_all(x, stri_locate_all_regex(x, "^Talk:.*\r", omit_no_match=TRUE)) <- "***"
print(x)
```

My output should be :

```r
x <-"12 3456 789", "***", "", NA, "***"
```

Any help ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I edited and added output, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```r
stri_sub_all(x, stri_locate_all_regex(x, "(?s)^Talk:.*", omit_no_match=TRUE)) <- "***"
```

The point here is to remove `\r` (your regex matched only the part of the line until CR char) and use `(?s)` with `.*` pattern to match the rest of the whole string, because `stringi` regex package uses ICU regex flavor and `.` does not match line break chars (like CR and LF) by default. `(?s)` enables `.` to match line breaks.

Probably a simpler approach is to use

```r
sub("^Talk:.*", "***", x)
```

Here, the default TRE regex library is used and `.` matches line breaks by default in this regex flavor.

Comment: Many thx for explanations, I'll used both

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to remove anything that occurs after the string `Talk` including `Talk`, then this should work:

```
sub("^Talk.*", "***", x)
[1] "12 3456 789" "***"         ""            NA            "***"
```